# JavaFX: GridPane, ObservableList and ListChangeListener

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

My question concerns the proper usage of ObservableList and ListChangeListeners in JavaFX (JavaFX 8, though I guess it would be similar in 2.x). As I'm a JavaFX beginner, I'm asking if I've understood correctly how they should be used.

Suppose I have a list of custom objects (let's call them Slots) which I'd want to render in a GridPane: each Slot would know where in the GridPane 'grid' it should go (= the row and the column data).

There will exist an initial (Array)List of Slots, but because the contents of the list are subject to change, I figure it'd make sense to create an ObservableList, and attach to it a ListChangeListener. However, I'm a little puzzled about what do with `change.wasUpdated()` etc. methods.

Does the following setup make sense:

```
public class SlotViewController {

@FXML
private GridPane pane;

private ObservableList<Slot> slots;

@FXML
public void initialize() {
    List<Slot> originalSlots = ...

    slots = FXCollections.observableList(originalSlots);
    slots.addListener(new ListChangeListener<Slot>() {

        @Override
        public void onChanged(ListChangeListener.Change<? extends Slot> change) {
            while (change.next()) {
                if (change.wasUpdated()) {
                    for (Slot slot : change.getList()) {
                        slot.update(pane);
                    }
                } else {
                    for (Slot removedSlot : change.getRemoved()) {
                        removedSlot.removeFrom(pane);
                    }

                    for (Slot addedSlot : change.getAddedSubList()) {
                        addedSlot.addTO(pane);
                    }
                } 
            }
        }

    });
}
```

wherein the Slot would then have methods `update(GridPane pane)`, `addTO(GridPane pane)` and removeFrom(GridPane pane)` that would look about like this:

(I don't have idea what I should do with `update(GridPane pane)`, though.)

```
public class Slot {

...

    public void addTo(GridPane pane) {
        // slot contents might be e.g. a couple of String labels in a HBox.
        pane.add(this.getSlotContents(), this.getColumn(), this.getRow());
    }

    public void removeFrom(GridPane pane) {
        pane.getChildren().remove(this);
        // ?
    }

    public void update(GridPane pane) {
        // ????
    }
}
```

(1) Overall, would this work, or am I missing something? Is this how `onChanged(ListChangeListener ...)` is supposed to be used?
(2) If yes, then how I should handle the update method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> (1) Overall, would this work, or am I missing something?

Yes, it looks like it should work.

> (2) If yes, then how I should handle the update method?

You probably don't need to.

**`ObservableList` update events and extractors:**

First, note that (according to the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ListChangeListener.Change.html#wasUpdated--)) the update events on the `ObservableList` are optional events (not all `ObservableList`s will fire them). Update events are intended to indicate that elements of the list have changed their value, while still remaining in the list at the same index. The way to have an `ObservableList` generate an update event is to create the list with an "extractor". For example, suppose your `Slot` class defines a `textProperty()`:

```
public class Slot {
    private final StringProperty text = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "text", "");
    public StringProperty textProperty() {
        return text ;
    }
    // ...
}
```

Then you can create an `ObservableList<Slot>` that will fire update events when the text property of any elements change by calling the [`FXCollections.observableArrayList(...)` method taking a `Callback`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#observableArrayList-javafx.util.Callback-):

```
ObservableList<Slot> slots = FXCollections.observableArrayList( 
    (Slot slot) -> new Observable[] {slot.textProperty()} );
```

The `Callback` here is a function mapping each slot to an array of `Observable`s: the list will observe those `Observable`s and fire update events if any of them change.

**The `GridPane` doesn't need to care about `Slot` updates:**

The reason you are unlikely to need this in your scenario is that the `Slot` class encapsulates both any data that could change to create update events, and the view of the `Slot`. So it can respond to changes in its data and update its view itself: the `GridPane` needs not know anything about these changes.

For a trivial example, suppose your `Slot` class just has a `textProperty()` as above and `getSlotContents()` just returns a simple `Label` displaying that text. You would have:

```
public class Slot {
    private final StringProperty text = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "text", "");
    public StringProperty textProperty() {
        return text ;
    }
    public final String getText() {
        return textProperty().get();
    }
    public final void setText(String text) {
        textProperty().set(text);
    }

    private final Label label = new Label();

    public Slot(String text) {
        label.textProperty().bind(text);
        setText(text);
    }

    public Node getSlotContents() {
        return label ;
    }
}
```

The `GridPane` need not be concerned about when the `textProperty()` of any `Slot` changes: the `Label`s displayed in the `GridPane` will be updated autonomously.

So your `ListChangeListener` can really just ignore `change`s for which `wasUpdated()` returns true; just handle the `wasAdded()` and `wasRemoved()` as you already do.

**An Alternative Solution**

If you want to consider an alternative solution to this using the [EasyBind framework](https://github.com/TomasMikula/EasyBind), first notice that you could manage the position of the `Slot` in the grid in the same way as shown above:

```
public class Slot {
    private final IntegerProperty column = new SimpleIntegerProperty(this, "column");
    public IntegerProperty columnProperty() {
        return column ;
    }
    public final int getColumn() {
        return columnProperty().get();
    }
    public final void setColumn(int column) {
        columnProperty().set(column);
    }

    // similarly for row...

    public Slot(int column, int row) {
        column.addListener((obs, oldColumn, newColumn) -> 
            GridPane.setColumnIndex(getSlotContents(), newColumn.intValue()));
        // similarly for row
        setColumn(column);
        setRow(row);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Now your `ListChangeListener` merely has to make sure that the `GridPane`s list of child nodes is always the result of calling `getSlotContents()` on the list of `Slot`s. You could just simplify your `ListChangeListener` implementation:

```
slots.addListener(new ListChangeListener<Slot>() {

    @Override
    public void onChanged(ListChangeListener.Change<? extends Slot> change) {
        while (change.next()) {
            if (change.wasAdded()) {
                for (Slot slot : change.getAddedSublist) {
                    pane.getChildren().add(slot.getSlotContents());
                }
            } else if (change.wasRemoved()) {
                for (Slot slot : change.getRemoved()) {
                    pane.getChildren().remove(slot.getSlotContents());
                }
            }
        }
    }

});
```

and remove the `addTo` and `removeFrom` methods from `Slot`.

Also note, though, that the `Bindings` class defines a method `bindContent` that binds the content of one list to an `ObservableList` of the same type. The [EasyBind framework](https://github.com/TomasMikula/EasyBind) allows you to create one `ObservableList` which is the result of mapping every element in another `ObservableList` via an arbitrary function.

So

```
ObservableList<Node> nodes = EasyBind.map(slots, Slot::getSlotContents);
```

creates an `ObservableList<Node>` that is always equal to the result of calling `getSlotContents()` on every element of `slots`.

This allows you to replace your `ListChangeListener` with a one-liner:

```
Bindings.bindContent(pane.getChildren(), 
    EasyBind.map(slots, Slot::getSlotContents));
```